# What is better for detection comments, split or substring

Tags: c#

I try to detect in C# Comments after ';'
Is it better to use Indexof and Substring or contains and split?
If i use index i get the ';' including all comments behind.
If i use contains and split i only get one comment but its less codelines.

```
            indexComment = 0;
            indexComment = line.IndexOf(";");
            if (indexComment >= 0)
            {
                commands = line.Substring(0, indexComment);
                comment = line.Substring(indexComment);
            }else
            {commands = line;}
```

VS

```
            if (line.Contains(";"))
            {
                commands = line.Split(';')[0];
                comment = line.Split(';')[1];
            }else
            {commands = line;}
```

Both codes works as expected but what would you prefer?
This is example code i want to detect

```
do something ;this line do something
x+5
;the line above add 5 to x
```

Comment: I believe comments will be ignore by the compiler at run time and you can not get that using either way.

Comment: Neither of these is a good answer.  Parsing C# is a difficult process that isn't as easy as looking for a semicolon.

Comment: `IndexOf` will return the first occurrence of a semi-colon, so your use with `substring` just grabs the rest of the string after the first occurrence of the semi-colon. `split` seperates the string on every occurrence of a semi-colon and place it into an array. So, if you have semi-colons in the comments, `split` will move those into separate places in the returned array, you could always use `string.join` on the array returned from `split` ignoring the first index of the array. Please provide some example data and expected results.

Comment: As an example, your own posted code contains several lines where a simple check for the first `;` falsely detects comments.

Comment: You might be better off checking for real start-of-comment markers: `//` and `/*`. But still you need to skip these in string literals

Comment: Thinking that comments come after a semicolon is completely false. I think you don't take many possibilities into account.

Comment: Its not C# comments 
its comment detection in c#

Comment: It probably depends on the language you are parsing. Could you provide all the non-terminal rules which contain the semi-colon terminal? Do you have a rule that enforces a newline at the end of a statement? If not, do you want to ignore everything after the first semicolon (so maybe other valid statements)? And finally, why don't you use a parser generator, parser combinator or another parser toolkit?

Comment: Its not a langueage its a txt with commands(maybe a better instructions) and comments and its very difficult to read.
luckily all comments are marked with ; . After seperation i write line number /tab 
command /tab comment to csv 

The hole c# script works great and i have to do litte change and dont know split or contain

Comment: @maf what you describe is a language, if you look at it the right way :) A well-formed input can be considered a language, especially if it contains command (than there is a chance, it is a programming language).
If you used a parser, probably it would not be so "difficult to read". You should read up something about text processing, parsing and/or regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The split seems better because builds the substrings for you.

Just add the Count parameter with 2, so if you have more than one ';', they will all be included in your comment variable.

And use a temporary variable to avoid splitting twice.

```
if (line.Contains(";"))
{
    string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ';' }, 2);
    commands = splitLine[0];
    comment = splitLine[1];
}
else
{ commands = line; }
```

Comment: Depends on the grammar of the parsed language. @maf do you have string/char literals in your language? If they can contain semicolons, this would fail.

Comment: why do you create a char array when you can use just `';'` or `";"`?

Comment: @Hawk Using the 'count' parameter requires the char array. It won't compile with just ';'.

Comment: if (line.Contains(';'))
works for this

Comment: This code sample fails on itself, because the semicolons in the strings would be considered the end of the line.

Comment: I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_ which is .NET Core, where it exists. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @SeanReid OP is not parsing a C# file. He did not provide the input format.

Comment: From the question I read it as him trying to find comments in C# code. Apparently he's since clarified in the comments he's trying to use C# to detect comments in an unspecified format.